Bell measurement for the $ [[5,1,3]] $ code
The $ [[5,1,3]] $ code is the smallest quantum error-correcting code (and it is the unique 5 qubit error-correcting code see Corollary 10 of Quantum codes of minimum distance two ), so sometimes it is nice to do out example with the $ [[5,1,3]] $ code to learn something.
For the sake of completeness I will provide the stabilizer generators for the $ [[5,1,3]] $ code:
\begin{align}
& XZZXI \\
& IXZZX \\
& XIXZZ \\
& ZXIXZ \\
\end{align}
Suppose I have two blocks of the $ [[5,1,3]] $ code, if you like you can think of this as a $ [[10,2,3]] $ code with stabilizer generators
\begin{align}
& XZZXIIIIII \\
& IXZZXIIIII \\
& XIXZZIIIII \\
& ZXIXZIIIII \\
& IIIIIXZZXI \\
& IIIIIIXZZX \\
& IIIIIXIXZZ \\
& IIIIIZXIXZ \\
\end{align}
Suppose I want to do a fault tolerant logical Bell measurement on my two logical qubits. How do I do that? My first idea would be to do a transversal $ CNOT $ then transversal $ H $ on the first block then do a fault tolerant measurement in the logical computational basis. But the $ [[5,1,3]] $ code doesn't have a transversal $ CNOT $ (or a transversal $ H $ for that matter) so I'm not sure what to do?

All stabilizer codes have fault tolerant transversal Bell basis measurement, because Bell basis measurement reveals $X_\text{left}X_\text{right} = \pm 1$ and $Z_\text{left}Z_\text{right} = \pm 1$ (by measuring them) which is very similar to how a qubit's worldline satisfies $X_\text{past}X_\text{future}=+1$ and $Z_\text{past}Z_\text{future}=+1$. Relating X and Z between two spacetime locations are core to why a code can store a qubit fault tolerantly, so the transversal Bell basis measurement is fault tolerant for the "same reason" that  the code is fault tolerant. It's just that the simultaneous-X-and-Z-relationship is across space instead of across time.
For example, here is fault tolerant transversal Bell measurement of two 5,1,3 codes:
import stim

circuit = stim.Circuit("""
    QUBIT_COORDS(0, 0) 0
    QUBIT_COORDS(0, 1) 1
    QUBIT_COORDS(1, 0) 2
    QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 3
    QUBIT_COORDS(2, 0) 4
    QUBIT_COORDS(2, 1) 5
    QUBIT_COORDS(3, 0) 6
    QUBIT_COORDS(3, 1) 7
    QUBIT_COORDS(4, 0) 8
    QUBIT_COORDS(4, 1) 9

    # Logical bell basis values known before noise
    MPP X0*X2*X4*X6*X8*X1*X3*X5*X7*X9
    MPP Z0*Z2*Z4*Z6*Z8*Z1*Z3*Z5*Z7*Z9
    TICK
    
    # Stabilizers known before noise
    MPP X0*Z2*Z4*X6 X1*Z3*Z5*X7
    MPP X2*Z4*Z6*X8 X3*Z5*Z7*X9
    MPP X4*Z6*Z8*X0 X5*Z7*Z9*X1
    MPP X6*Z8*Z0*X2 X7*Z9*Z1*X3
    TICK
    
    # Noise applied.
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    TICK

    # Noisy transversal XX measurement.
    MXX(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    # Compare original logical XX to logical XX recovered from physical MXXs.
    OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-3] rec[-4] rec[-5] rec[-15]
    TICK

    # Noisy transversal ZZ measurement.
    MZZ(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    # Compare original logical ZZ to logical ZZ recovered from physical MZZs.
    OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(1) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-3] rec[-4] rec[-5] rec[-19]
    # Compare the original stabilizers across the spacelike measurements.
    DETECTOR(0, 1, 0) rec[-3] rec[-4] rec[-7] rec[-10] rec[-17] rec[-18]
    DETECTOR(1, 1, 0) rec[-2] rec[-3] rec[-6] rec[-9] rec[-15] rec[-16]
    DETECTOR(2, 1, 0) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-8] rec[-10] rec[-13] rec[-14]
    DETECTOR(3, 1, 0) rec[-1] rec[-5] rec[-7] rec[-9] rec[-11] rec[-12]
""")

err = circuit.search_for_undetectable_logical_errors(
    dont_explore_edges_with_degree_above=10,
    dont_explore_edges_increasing_symptom_degree=False,
    dont_explore_detection_event_sets_with_size_above=10,
    canonicalize_circuit_errors=True,
)
print("Code Distance is ", len(err))
# prints 3


Could you maybe explain the beginning of you answer in more detail? When you say "all codes" do you mean "all stabilizer codes" or are you even allowing non-additive codes? What does it mean for a "code to reveal" and what does it mean for a code to be a "quantum memory"?

@EricKubischta Yeah i should have said all stabilizer codes. It's a very general property, it would also work on floquet codes and etc with some conditions on lining up the time dynamics, but for non-additive codes you might run into issues due to the need for Clifford corrections.
